# Adminimal template and CCS adjustments and priority of css files?

Tags: 7, theming

In Drupal 7 i use the adminimal template for some pages.

I want to adjust some element and added therefore a SASV file into the theme.
Now some elements I can override but some elements (like table th) are not going well. Looking into a deeper way I can see the priority of the files:

1 custom.css (with my adjustments)
2 reset.css
3 style.css

So Style.css is applied as last. But style css is not in the info file?!?!

In the adminimal.info file I added:

```
; ========================================
; Stylesheets
; ========================================
stylesheets[all][] = css/custom.css
```

How to change the order of this processing ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

```
 drupal_add_css($adminimal_path . '/css/custom.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'media' => 'all', 'weight' => 2));
```

in the template.php file